# How widely supported is Decaf in browsers?

Tags: javascript, ruby, browser, webkit

Recently, I came across [Decaf](http://trydecaf.org/). This utility brings Ruby to the browser. Basically as far as I have read and understood, Decaf has a lot of wrapper functions over Webkit which lets you manipulate and play around it instead of using Javascript.

There have been several attempts to achieve the target of having Ruby in the browser. Once such project that I know of is [Opalrb](http://opalrb.org/).

But, will these work on the older browsers. Or the existing ones? Mobile? What about the browsers who do not use Webkit?

*PS: I have not tried either of the libraries*

Answer (score 5):

Decaf is not a library and almost certainly is not what you are looking for. Decaf provides native support for ruby at the browser level and hence would require your end users to have decaf installed as well. Also it is available for only Mac. Think of it as a new browser (albeit a webkit fork) which treats ruby as first class citizen.

Opal is a compiler that compiles (a subset of ) ruby code to javascript which can run in all browsers. Plus opal has bindings for jquery and an mvc framework in works to ease development. So if you are looking forward to creating a web application for the masses Opal is the way to go.

For the sake of completion, I should mention that there are many academic/experimental projects older than Opal which have attempted to do similar things eg. Hotruby, RubyJS etc. Opal is much more actively developed compared to these projects and a significant amount of effort has been devoted to optimization in practical scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Decaf is a new project which has ruby embedded and providing javascript equivalent binding for browser and events in ruby.

It will not work in older browsers.

Opal compiles ruby to javascript then runs it, but decaf runs natively.

Comment: so better go with Opal than Decaf ?